# Why always the last reference to the object is used in loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `assemblyEl` is created correctly(1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg), but the ajax request always sends the last id(3).

Why this happens and how to fix it?

```
var assemblies = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];

for (var a in assemblies) {
    var assembly = assemblies[a];

    var assemblyEl = $('<img src="' + assembly.id + '.jpg" />')
                        .click(function () {
                                 $.ajax({
                                     type: "POST",
                                     url: url,
                                     data: { id: assembly.id },
                                     async: false,
                                     success: function (data) {
                                     }
                                 });
                         });
}
```

Comment: does assemblies have to be in this format?

Comment: wait, do you mean you dont want to send id 3?

Comment: Please, stop using `for...in` loops on arrays. They're slow and unstable.

Comment: @Matt, what do you suggest to use?

Comment: `for(var i = 0;i<assemblies.length;i++)...` If you insist on using a, you can change the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the click event fires when the element is clicked. By the time that happens, the value of `assembly` is the last value in the loop.

Use a closure to copy the value to the new scope.

```
function clickHandler(assembly) {
    return function () {
         $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: url,
              data: { id: assembly.id },
              async: false,
              success: function (data) {
              }
          });
    };
}

.click(clickHandler(assembly));
```

Comment: but the 'click' happens after the creation of the elements

Comment: You can also do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192348/closures-in-a-for-loop. Internally a closure is made, too.