# setTimeout only sees last value in array?

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
>   [How do I pass the value (not the reference) of a JS variable to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function)
>   [Why always the last reference to the object is used in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599157/why-always-the-last-reference-to-the-object-is-used-in-loop)

I have an array of ids which I loop over and want to use in a function called by setTimeout, however when "func" below is executed it only seems to see the last id stored in the array.
I have been trying to uses closures to fix the issue but have had no success.

```
  // loop over array an call setTimeout for loading an image
  for (var i = 0; i < idlist.length; i++) {
    // variable i want use in function
    var lookup = idlist[i];

    var func = function() {
        alert(lookup); // this is always the last value in the "idlist" array
    };

    setTimeout(func, 500);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate. There is *only one* variable called `lookup`. Please search on SO.

Comment: Usually I find things on SO pretty easily, sorry for the duplicate, but for anyone interested the solution I used was [How do I pass the value (not the reference) of a JS variable to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function) as suggested in the links at the top of the page.