# how to add onclick event on anchor tag that is generated with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using only javascript, not jQuery or no other javascript frameworks.

I have created one anchor tag like:

```
var _a = document.createElement('a');
```

now I want to add onclick for this tag. I have tried following:

```
_a.onclick = function(){ mycode(id); }
```

The function applies on that but the anchor tags are create in loop... so `mycode(id)` is always taking the last value of the loop.

Can any one help me out in this ?

Comment: Show us the entire loop. You simply need a closure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript function is using the last known parameters in loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439700/javascript-function-is-using-the-last-known-parameters-in-loop), [Javascript - Dynamically assign onclick event in the loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040069/javascript-dynamically-assign-onclick-event-in-the-loop) and many more

Comment: scroll down to "Looping with a closure" [here](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following:

```
_a.onclick = (function(id){return function(){ mycode(id); }})(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need a function to create your handler like this:

```
function createHandler( id ) {
  return function(){ mycode( id ); };
}
```

and then assign inside the loop

```
for ( i= ... ) {
   _a.onclick = createHandler( i );
}
```

On the other hand you maybe should use `addEventListener()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)) to add events to elements:

```
_a.addEventListener( 'click', createHandler( i ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var id = 0; id < 10; id++){
    var _a = document.createElement('a');
    _a.onclick = (function(id){
        return function (){
            mycode(id);
        }
    })(id);
}
```

That should fix it.