# Imitate onclick event on several elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I need to solve a little problem of simulation of user's actions on site: select certain `<option>` tag in `<select>` and then imitate pressing the button "OK". There are several rows  with `<select>` tags so I decided do it in a for loop with jQuery. But this code works only in the first iteration (but works pretty well - numbers changing and then alert('gooood-goood') shows).

Interestingly, the loop continues and vars 'option' and 'select' assigned just as they should, even `alert()` of the second button shows, indicating that event `onclick` worked, but `<select>` tags in second row remained at zero, and there was no simulate of `onclick` event actually. This code seemed to refuse to work in all loops of the cycle, but the first.

The ultimate goal - to simulate the user and solve exactly on JavaScript is not required.
I have a dynamically changing parameters in the loop, I think that Selenium IDE may be the answer for me but I need it work with some logic and changed parameters in the loop.

Here two lists: script and html where script should be executed.

```html
<input type="button" id="done" value="C'mon" />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="c10">
      <select name="c0">
        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="c11">
      <select name="c1">
        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="c12">
      <input value="OK" type="button" onclick="alert('gooood-goood')" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="c20">
      <select name="c0">
        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="c21">
      <select name="c1">
        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</optiaon>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="c22">
      <input value="OK" type="button" onclick="alert('gooood-goood')" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And script then:

```js
function foo() {
  alert('inside');
  
  var comb = rand(10, 99) + '', row = 1, col = 0;

  for (; row <= 2; row++) {
    for (; col <= 1; col++) {
      var select = '#c' + row + col + ' select[name=c' + col + ']';
      var option = "#c" + row + col + " select option[value=" + comb[col] + "]";

      $(select).change(function () {
        $(option).prop('selected', true);
      });

      $(select).change();

      if (col == 1) {
        var i = col + 1;
        $('#c' + row + i + ' input').click();
      }
    }
    
    col = 0;
    comb = rand(10, 99);
  }
}

$(function () {
  document.getElementById('done').onclick = foo;
});


function rand(min, max) { // Generate a random integer
  if (max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  } else {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (min + 1));
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I don't know what I've done, but it's working now.  Same code :/

Comment: It's your typical JavaScript "function-in-a-loop" problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript function is using the last known parameters in loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439700/javascript-function-is-using-the-last-known-parameters-in-loop)

Comment: I misunderstanding something general in javascript scopes. Can't get it, if vars 'select' and 'option' change, why $(select).change() doesn't work with new var 'select' for example in second iteration?

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
>  var option = "#c"+ row + col + " select option[value=" + comb[col] + "]";
> 
>  $(select).change(function(){
> 
>    $(option).prop('selected', true);
>  });
```

The variable *option* in the change function has a closure to the outer *option* variable, so the value will be whatever *option* was when the loop ended, which is (where `comb[col]` is set to `6`):

```
 "#c21 select option[value=6]";
```

BTW, the way you are selecting a digit from *comb* will fail in browsers that don't allow access to string characters by index (some versions of IE at least) and means the *rand* function may as well just return a number from 0 to 9 inclusive.

You can solve the first issue using something like:

```
comb.substring(1,2)
```

or

```
 comb.charAt(1)
```

which makes what you are doing a lot more obvious.

Have you considered instead just getting the form controls and iterating over those, independently of the table structure? It would be very much simpler.

Comment: _Have you considered instead just getting the form controls and iterating over those, independently of the table structure? It would be very much simpler._ Can you be more specific? I've lost you here:(

Comment: Did you mean get all neccesary DOM elements and give them event handlers on change and click?

Comment: The [form.elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76728479) collection gives you all the form controls regardless of the page structure. All tests can then be based on the control name independently of the document layout.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i just realized. `comb = rand(10, 99);` after first iteration became not a string.

Just need to fix that `comb = rand(10, 99) + '';`