# Javascript variable scope in "for...in..." loops?

Tags: javascript, scope

Say I have a code-snippet:

```
dict = {"key":"elem"}
for (var elem in dict){
    someFunction(function(){
        anotherFunction(dict[elem]);
    })
}
```

Is `elem` still that temporary variable created in the `for...in...` statement when it is referenced at that third level, i.e. at `anotherFunction(dict[elem])`?

When it gets called in my code, I get an error saying that it returns undefined.

EDIT: could I somehow fix this with a `this` keyword somewhere?

Comment: A loop has no notion of a scope. What is the `dict` variable? Object or Array?

Comment: There is only **one** variable named `elem` -- what does this imply about the *value* it evaluates to at the usage site? (Hint: *only new function scopes can introduce a new variables*.) Look for "javascript loop last value closure" or similar.

Comment: Your edit is nonsense, how can it b fixed with `this` somewhre?

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425062/passing-functions-to-settimeout-in-a-loop-always-the-last-value , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520587/variable-in-javascript-callback-functions-always-gets-last-value-in-loop , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599157/why-always-the-last-reference-to-the-object-is-used-in-loop (this might not be *the* problem, bit is *a* problem)

Comment: Ok, sorry, dict is an object, say, defined as `dict = {"key" : "val"}`

Comment: FYI: `elem` is not a temporary value. As long as the scope object of `elem` exists, it will be available in that scope.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a closure over the anonymous function so it depends on what you do with the variable between setting it and using it.

```
var dict = {
    "a": "aaaaaaaaa",
    "b": "bbbbbbbbb",
    "c": "ccccccccc"
};

for (var elem in dict) {
    someFunction(function() {
        anotherFunction(dict[elem]);
    })
}

function anotherFunction(a) {
    console.log(a);
}
```

Async:  The loop runs through before actually executing the code so `elem` winds up being the last key in the set.  The last key gets used several times.

```
function someFunction(f) {   
    setTimeout(f, 500);
}
```

Synchronous:  Each function runs in order, so each value gets printed out

```
function someFunction(f) {
    f();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`elem` is defined your problem is that:

```
dict[elem]
```

returns `undefind`

Answer (score 0):

If you create a variable inside any statement the variable will still be scoped to the closest parent function, that's how JavaScript works. Scopes are functions. You should be able to use `elem` there though so your problem must be somewhere else as **gdoron** said.

**Edit:**

It seems that you're calling a function that takes another function as a parameter. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: The first part is true. I suspect the issue is related to not understand this (or just not having the right data, or not using a lexical variable or, ...)

Answer (score 0):

To use the `dict` variable as the scope of `anotherFunction`, you need to reference `dict` as the scope of that function. Example:

```
for (var elem in dict) {
  someFunction(function(dict, elem) {
    return anotherFunction.call(dict, elem);
  }
}
```

In your `anotherFunction` structure, the usage of the `this` keyword would reference the `dict` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call