# Closures affecting variables in a closed function within a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, closures

```
this.config = {
    source: psource,
    _events: [
        'value1',
        'value2',
        'value3'
    ]
};

// Add callbacks to source
var that = this;
for (var i = this.config._events.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var name = this.config._events[i];
    console.log(name); // correct

    $(this.config.source).on(name, function() {
        console.log(name); // value1
        console.log(that.config._events[i]); // undefined
    });
}
```

I can't see what is wrong here. I removed all the complicated versions and put in the simplest, it just doesn't want to work at all. The first `console.log` correctly outputs all the correct names, but it acts like the loop happens all at once, then does it again for the inner `console.log`'s.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: The statement "Closures are affecting everything, not just this" isn't describing a problem - that's how closures work. All variables in the enclosing scope are included in the closure.

Comment: Please modify the title of the question with something more descriptive. I think you should mention the term `for loop`

Comment: duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192348/closures-in-a-for-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that block

`console.log(that.config._events[i]); // undefined`

`i` would end up being -1 every time your closure is called.

You would have to do something of the sort in order to create a closure around `i`

```
$(this.config.source).on(name, function(i) { return function() {
        console.log(name); // value1
        console.log(that.config._events[i]); // undefined
    };
}(i) );
```

Comment: Even better, pass `i` as an argument to the `.on` method, and access the variable using `event.i` . For more details on my suggestion, see the documentation of `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @RobW This would probably work in this situation since i is a numeric primitive. However, I deliberately chose this solution so that the op can understand that keeping a reference to a variable in the closure does not equate to keeping a reference to the current value of it at the time of the closure creation.

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript, it is not recommended to define a function inside a `for` loop.

Instead, You should use a javascript lib that provides `each` e.g. `underscore`. Then your code will look like this:

```
    _.each(this.config._events, function(e) {
       $(this.config.source).on(name, function() {
          console.log(e);
       });
```

You might want to reverse the array before.

Here is the [doc for _.each](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each)

You can also use jQuery's `$.each` which provides a similar interface.

Comment: -1 It is perfectly safe to define a function inside a `for` loop. You just have to be aware of variable scope and how closures work.

Comment: I replaced `not safe` by `dangerous`. This leads to a lot of confusion. In fact, `jslint` doesn't allow it. Please vote up back

Comment: nothing dangerous about it either. It works just as it should. I stand by my -1. That `jslint` does not allow it is their choice, not a javascript issue.