# How can I make sure the addEventListener doesn't ignore the iteration of the i var in my for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a userscript that will make lots of buttons, and I can't seem to give them all an unique function.

I already tried

```
 downArrow.onclick = function (){downVote(id, username)};<br>
```

and

```
 downArrow.onclick = "downVote(\"" + id + "\", \"" + username + "\")";
```

But they don't work. Then I read somewhere that only the following works:

```
 downArrow.addEventListener('click', downVote(id, username), false);
```

This causes that all the buttons will only downvote the last ID and username of the iteration.

I want them all to have unique onclick functions.

Entire for loop:

```
var targetPosts = document.getElementsByClassName("thing message");
for (var i=0;i<targetPosts.length;i++) 
    {
    try
      {
        id = targetPosts[i].getAttribute("data-fullname");
        username = targetPosts[i].childNodes[4].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].innerHTML;

        var upArrow=document.createElement("DIV");
        upArrow.className = "arrowUp";
        upArrow.id = id + "up";
        upArrow.addEventListener('click', function(){ upVote(id, username)} , false);

        var downArrow=document.createElement("DIV");
        downArrow.className = "arrowDown";
        downArrow.id = id + "down";
        downArrow.addEventListener('click', function(){ downVote(id, username)} , false

      targetPosts[i].childNodes[3].appendChild(upArrow);
      targetPosts[i].childNodes[3].appendChild(downArrow);
      }
    catch(err){}
    }
```

Comment: This is the Javascript's infamous lack of block scope.

Comment: Where's the for loop? Post all the code here?

Comment: Is downArrow a different element each time yes?

Comment: Yep. I put the entire for loop there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) and [Closures in a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192348/closures-in-a-for-loop).

Comment: This question has been asked like 10000 times here... :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bind was invented for exactly such a case :

```
 upArrow.addEventListener('click', upVote.bind(upArrow, id, username), false);
```

should do the job.

Comment: You probably want `upVote.bind(upVote, id, username)` because event handlers' value of `this` refers to the element it's bound to

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'm used to doing this where the handler doesn't **just** call a function, and needs the value of `this`. I was thinking of something else, sorry :)

Comment: This one works. I don't know why it works, but it does. What does bind do different than all the other things?

Comment: @lan : you made a typo, but still you were right : i changed : upVote.bind(null, id, username) to upVote.bind(upArrow, id, username).

Comment: @VincentPiel Ahh yeah, sorry. I'm confusing myself because they both start with "up"!

Comment: @Marteen : google "MDN bind" for the details, but basically bind creates a new function that has 'this' set to first element, and its arguments set to the arguments that follows. Since binding arguments are evaluated when bind is called, the bound function 'remembers' the value of id.

Comment: only beware that it can be not supported in some browsers (but can be easily added if missing).

Comment: @lupatus : yes, MDN provides the code to support bind in all browsers. Note also that since 'bind' creates a new function, you have to store it somewhere if you plan on removing the event handler later.@lan : i was confused so i checked on MDN : the value of this is set when adding an event listener in html, not in javascript. Another weird rule...

Answer (score 3):

Since JavaScript has no block scope (will come with ES6) try the following:

```
downArrow.addEventListener('click', function(uid, uname) {
    return function() {
        downVote(uid, uname);
    };
}(id, username), false);
```

When invoking the anonymous function (happens immediately) you capture the current state of `id` and `username` and use it when the inner function is invoked (happens when the user clicks the button).

In ES6 you can use `let id = ...` to define a variable with block scope and your posted code should work fine.

Comment: I'm going to try this now.

Comment: Your inner function call needs to be `downVote(uid, uname);` since those are the parameters of the IIFE

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you're trying to do that (would be better to show loop code), but in general its not very secure to create functions within the loop because you can by mistake reference to variable being changed inside a loop so finally you'll get all functions using same id. solution for that is to use some helper function:

```
var bindClick = function (element, id, username) {
        element.addEventListener('click', function () {
            downVote(id, username);
        }, false);
    },
    i, mybutton;
for (i = 0 ; i < amountOfUsers ; ++i) {
    mybutton = document.getElementById('downvote-handle-' + i);
    bindClick(mybutton, i, usernames[i]);
}
```

this way `i` value is copied (passed by value) and is safe.

it can be done also with anonymous function, result will be the same (but IMHO less readable):

```
for (i = 0 ; i < amountOfUsers ; ++i) {
    mybutton = document.getElementById('downvote-handle-' + i);
    (function (element, id, username) {
        element.addEventListener('click', function () {
            downVote(id, username);
        }, false);
    }(mybutton, i, userames[i])); 
}
```

Comment: So basically that would add unique functions to all those buttons after they're created, instead of being in the same loop as them being created?

Comment: @MaartenBoogaard No, you call the `bindClick` function inside the original loop, which passes things to the function and binds the event. So there's nothing unnecessary. I prefer this way

Comment: Nope, sorry, what I wrote is a little bit stupid ;) - you'll still have same problem as I described at first. I'll update my answer.